# How can I synchronize two or more Spring contexts with RabbitMQ? Broadcasting messages/events?

Tags: spring, events, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I'm currently evaluating some ideas how to manage an event synchronization between multiple Spring application contexts, i.e. a Tomcat cluster.

In that use case, each of the contexts can produce an event X (regardless a *Spring context event* or a self-made one) which have to be broadcasted to all other context instances. The event is only valid in it's "life cycle" which means that I don't want to persist it in any way (because they are many and their state will be obsolet after minutes).

My idea is to use a already present RabbitMQ instance. However, the standard producer/consumer pattern won't fit, because the event should be broadcasted to all consumers. Each consumer is a producer.. just like a chatroom.

Q #1: Is this possible with RabbitMQ (+Spring Integration)? How can I build such a broadcast message setup?

Q #2: Whether this is possible or not? Has anyone a better solution/idea?

The use case: Each web application context can produce events like "user x invites user y" which should be transported asap to the user's browser via Websocket or EventSource or something else. Because this are (already) running requests, it is possible that the place of action (server 1) is not the place of consuming (server 2).

The main goals for a solution are:

1. (Relatively) Fast and scalable.
2. Fire & Forget. If the message was sent, destroy it. If the message is irrelevant, forget it. No persist. In RabbitMQ, that could be made with a TTL.
3. The message is being serialized against a model, i.e. with Jackson or something like this.
4. No manual configuration based on the number of (active) contexts/nodes. If I would add an additional context (web server, backend process, what ever), I don't want to modify the synchronization setup.

## Update 1

After reading the anwser of [Gary Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) , I've played it little bit.

```
    <beans profile="rabbit">
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" channel-cache-size="10" host="${rabbitmq.host}"
                               port="${rabbitmq.port}" username="${rabbitmq.username}"
                               password="${rabbitmq.password}" virtual-host="${rabbitmq.virtualhost}"/>
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <rabbit:queue id="eventQueue" name="${rabbitmq.queue.springevents}" auto-delete="false" durable="true"></rabbit:queue>

    <bean id="amqpTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="exchange" value="${rabbitmq.springevents.exchange.fanout}"/>
        <property name="replyTimeout" value="${rabbitmq.replyTimeout}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Receiving -->
    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="mqEventInChannelJson"
                                      queue-names="${rabbitmq.queue.springevents}"/>

    <!-- Sending -->
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="mqEventOutChannelJson" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" routing-key=""
                                       exchange-name="${rabbitmq.springevents.exchange.fanout}" />
</beans>
```

Channel mqEventOutChannelJson -> Rabbit Exchange (amqp.fanout) ->

If I use this configuration, multiple parallel starts will skip events because all running processes run on the same queue (*rabbitmq.queue.springevents*). Is there any possibility to create custom queue names without provide each node a different configuration?

I've tested it with a separated Virtualhost and the exchange *amqp.fanout*. Same to a specific Fanout exchange.

## Update 2

To ensure that each consumer has it's own queue, I have created an unique application id for each one.

The bean *application* itself created an unique identifier:

```
@Component("application")
public class Application {

private String id;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    id = "app" + Math.round(1000 * Math.random());
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

Given this, I can create on the fly an unique queue which is registered on a common exchange. No external configuration steps are required.

```
    <util:property-path id="applicationId" path="application.id" />
    <rabbit:queue id="eventQueue" name="${rabbitmq.queue.springevents}_#{applicationId}" auto-delete="true" durable="true" exclusive="true">
        <rabbit:queue-arguments>
            <!-- Attention if you want to declare mixed value types: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP-198 -->
            <entry key="x-message-ttl">
                <value type="java.lang.Long">${rabbitmq.queue.ttl}</value>
            </entry>
        </rabbit:queue-arguments>
    </rabbit:queue>
```

Comment: If you used something like CometD, Atmosphere, or some fancy AJAX (maybe Spring's DeferedResult or something) you could "subscribe" the clients (browsers) to a Topic and just let the client determine if they care about a particular message or not.  I know Atmosphere has a JMS plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [RabbitMQ topic exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html) or a [fanout exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html) and have each consumer bind a queue to it. Completely supported by Spring AMQP and Spring Integration.

Comment: Yeah, that's feels and sounds like what I want. Just forgot the exchange thing.. I update my question a little bit.